# How to combat an internal error in Xcode Storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

All of a sudden I am running into this error on the `Main.storyboard` for this swift project I'm working on

> "Internal error. Please file a bug at bug report.apple.com and attach
>   *******/T/IB-agent-diagonstics"

I have cleaned the projected, turned system on and off and updated to Xcode 7.1.1.

I will file a bug report but I am running short on my deadline now and really need to keep moving with his project! Don't have an older version either.

Anyone managed to resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: I get this problem sometimes after fixing merge conflicts in git. Typically I will open the storyboard in my text editor of choice (Vim, Emacs, etc) or you can right click on your storboard > open as > source code and see if the problem is in there.

Answer (score 6):

I faced the same issue. And it was solved by cleaning up the build files number of times.

**cmd + shift + k**

AND

**cmd + option + shift + k**